# How can i make a sprite with intercambiable images

Tags: iphone, flash, air, pfi

How can i get sprite thats updates the image with this interface?

```
public class DinImageSprite extends Sprite
{
    public function DinImageSprite() { 
        super(); 
    }

    public setImage(a:Class) {

    }
}
```

Tanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit your question and elaborate more on what you are passing into the set image function.
Or you can be more vague so we can keep on guessing.

```
public setImage(a:Image) {
  this.addChild( a );
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain exactly what you want. You mentioned nothing about several times. I don't read minds.